# Add heading on csv using fputcsv php

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I'm trying to input some data into a csv file and it works nicely, but if I try to add the header of the table of data Excel won't let me open the file, because "the file format and extension of file.csv don't match. the file could be corrupted or unsafe".

Here's the code:

```
//crate headers
$headers[] = "ID";
$headers[] = "Name";
$headers[] = "Ref";
$headers[] = "Quantity";

// crete and open file  
$csvName = "file.csv";
$fileHandle = fopen($csvName, 'w') or die('Can\'t create .csv file, try again later.');

//Add the headers, if I take this line out the excel allows me to open the file
fputcsv($fileHandle,$headers,";");

//Add the data
for($i = 0; $i < count($info); ++$i) {
    fputcsv($fileHandle,$info[$i],";");
}

//close file
fclose($fileHandle);
```

EDIT:

Here are the first lines of my csv open with notepad:

ID;Name;Ref;Quantity

2;"Blouse - Color : White, Size : M";demo_2;6

3;"Printed Dress - Color : Orange, Size : S";demo_3;4

Comment: The way you are using single and doublequotes scars me mentally. You should use single quotes on anything that doesn't need [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation), and double quotes for anything that does. Basically, all of your double quotes should be single quotes in your code

Comment: Can you open your csv file output in a text editor and share it's contents with us? Maybe just the first 3-4 lines are all that's needed

Comment: Yes I know, I originally had single quotes, I changed from single quotes to double quotes just to check if it would make it work for some reason, but it didn't. Forgot to change it back.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're intending to use this to create a CSV file that can be opened normally with Excel, the headers shouldn't need to be wrapped in double quotes (because they don't contain any separator characters), and you should use commas rather than semicolons for the separators. However, if you make those changes, *you'll still get the same error message* when you try to open the resulting file with Excel. Surprisingly, this is [because your headers start with 'ID'](https://annalear.ca/2010/06/10/why-excel-thinks-your-csv-is-a-sylk/).

If you can use a different name for that first column header, it could simplify things a bit.

```
$headers = ["ItemID", "Name", "Ref", "Quantity"];

$csvName = "file.csv";
$fileHandle = fopen($csvName, 'w') or die('Can\'t create .csv file, try again later.');

//Add the headers
fputcsv($fileHandle, $headers);

//Add the data
foreach ($info as $item) {
    fputcsv($fileHandle, $item);
}

//close file
fclose($fileHandle);
```

This should create a .csv file that will open in Excel with no errors.

Comment: WOW! I could have never imagined it was because of that, now is working perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your headers to this:

```
$headers[] = '"ID"';
$headers[] = '"Name"';
$headers[] = '"Ref"';
$headers[] = '"Quantity"';
```

This will wrap the strings in double quotes, which should fix the syntax issues you are experiencing.

Comment: fputcsv will add extra quotes around because of the quotes in the strings.

Comment: I just tested it in PHP and get: `"""ID""","""Name""","""Ref""","""Quantity"""`

Comment: Thanks! This worked! It wrapped the strings in double quotes as @manassehkatz said, but at least I can access the file.

Comment: @Sefean Take a look at my answer - basically if you hardcode the header line you can get it just right, plus commas instead of semicolons make Excel work a little smoother. If you actually have a lot of fields then switch back to an array for the header but make your own loop to output it instead of using the not-quite-compatible-with-Excel fputcsv function.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is picky. PHP by default uses commas, which is actually what you want to use for Excel. Semicolons will often work but are not the default - remember, CSV stands for *Comma* Separated Values. The second problem is specific to Excel. Even though it handles strings without quotes just fine in the data section, for some reason it doesn't work well on the header line. I don't see an option in fputcsv to force quotes, so you need to hardcode them. Something like:

```
// create and open file  
$csvName = "file.csv";
$fileHandle = fopen($csvName, 'w') or die("Can't create .csv file, try again later.");

//Add the headers - note that \r\n or \n is OS dependent
fwrite($fileHandle,'"ID","Name","Ref","Quantity"' . "\r\n");

//Add the data
for ($i = 0; $i < count($info); ++$i) {
    fputcsv($fileHandle,$info[$i]);
}

//close file
fclose($fileHandle);
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, it put the headers in only 1 cell fo Excel, something like this:
(each column separated by '-')


ID;Name;Ref;Quantity
2 - NameWhatever - demo_1 - 2
3 - NameWhatever - demo_1 - 2

Comment: Did you also change the data fputcsv to use commas (default) instead of semicolons? If you didn't then Excel will get confused, though when I tried it that way I ended up with the headers OK and the data all one cell per line.

Comment: Yes, changing everything to commas make it write only in the first column, because, Excel wants semicolons instead of commas.

Comment: @Sefean What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016