# Cannot use string value from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with two string values, but cannot use one of them. If I use

```
var_dump($array[0]);
```

it's result is

```
 array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "01" ["name"]=> string(10) "Aquamarine" }
```

but

```
var_dump($array[0]["id"]);
```

shows me NULL.

I've tried changing "id" to sth else, tried using ' instead of ", with the same effect, strlen($array[0]["id"]) also returns 0. The second one ("name") works just fine.

Update:
The array is initalized with this code:

```
$handle = @fopen("stones.csv", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ';')) !== false) {
        if (empty($fields)) {
            $fields = $row;
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($row as $k=>$value) {
            $array[$i][$fields[$k]] = $value;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_dump($array[0]);
var_dump($array[0]["id"]);
var_dump(array_keys($array[0]));
```

So there are no modifications between dumps, last three rows return this

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "01" ["name"]=> string(10) "Aquamarine" } NULL array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "id" [1]=> string(4) "name" }
```

Now I see that there are some invisible characters in the "id" key, so the next question is how to get rid of them?

Comment: Can you possibly show the code where you initialized the array?

Comment: Might be worth checking `var_dump(array_keys($array[0]));` and see if there are some invisible characters in the key.

Comment: updated the post with initialization code and dump results

Comment: Not seeing where `$i` is initialized. If that's null, it could cause issues.

Comment: `$i` is initialized as 0

Comment: `string(5) "id"` does that not look suspicious to you? The key is not simply `id` the 2 characters, thus you can't access it as such.

Comment: Did you open this CSV in Excel? It could be related to this weird thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45489860/2734189

Comment: Don't have time to investigate right now, but thank's to @JonStirling comment. I just hardcoded the names of fields instead of parsing them from csv file. Post an answer pls so I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

trim the key using builtin "trim" function. ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$handle = @fopen("stones.csv", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ';')) !== false) {
        if (empty($fields)) {
            $fields = $row;
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($row as $k=>$value) {
            $array[$i][trim($fields[$k])] = $value;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_dump($array[0]);
var_dump($array[0]["id"]);
var_dump(array_keys($array[0]));
```

Comment: Nope, this does not help. Anyways, thanks for your time, I've found the solution already.